# D3 custom colors inside a single series of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I am currently working through some charting for a client and finding it hard to customize colors exactly how I want. I am using D3 inside React and using the rumble-charts npm module.

Here is a crude example of the data:

```
const series = [{ data: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }];
```

And here is a crude example of how I might render that data

```
<Chart width={300} height={150} series={series} minY={0}>
  <Layer width='80%' height='90%' position='top center'>
    <Bars
      groupPadding='3%'
      innerPadding='0.5%'
      colors={[['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']]}
    />
  </Layer>
</Chart>
```

In essence, I just want to have negative values displayed in red and positive values displayed in blue. Seems simple enough to me, but when one defines multiple colors they are used for series' and not for individual values.

Comment: Is a CSS based solution good for you?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If I can reliably target negative values I could live with it.

Comment: Share your D3 code. It's quite easy to pass a function for the colour...

Comment: @CoolBlue The D3 code is insude the rumble-charts npm module

Answer (score 0):

In a CSS based solution, first set the CSS for colouring the bars according to their class:

```
.positiveBar {
    fill: blue;
}

.negativeBar {
    fill: red;
}
```

After that, set the class of the bar according to it's value:

```
.attr("class", function(d) { 
    return (d > 0) ? "positiveBar" : "negativeBar"; 
})
```